# Pandas merge two dataframes by date, ending up with entire NaN column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I've gone through a number of examples of similar queries unfortunately to no avail.
I have two dataframes that I need to combine.

**df1**

```html
     .       DATE            HIGH         LOW  OPEN  CLOSE
0 2013-01-04 10734.23 10602.24 10604.50 10688.11
1 2013-01-07 10743.69 10589.70 10743.69 10599.01
2 2013-01-08 10602.12 10463.43 10544.21 10508.06
3 2013-01-09 10620.70 10398.61 10405.67 10578.57
4 2013-01-10 10686.12 10619.65 10635.11 10652.64
5 2013-01-11 10830.43 10748.06 10786.14 10801.57
6 2013-01-15 10952.31 10851.66 10914.65 10879.08
7 2013-01-16 10806.41 10591.30 10806.41 10600.44
```

**df2**

```html
.        Date          sentiment
0 2013-01-01     -0.027282
1 2013-01-02     0.063613
2 2013-01-03     0.091363
3 2013-01-04     0.092818
4 2013-01-05     -0.019002
5 2013-01-06     -0.033752
6 2013-01-07     0.060038
7 2013-01-08     0.081649
8 2013-01-09     -0.031924
9 2013-01-10     0.109111
10 2013-01-11   -0.057070
11 2013-01-12   -0.052431
12 2013-01-13   0.014726
13 2013-01-14   0.047232
14 2013-01-15   0.060790
15 2013-01-16   -0.067828
16 2013-01-17   -0.035174
```

**code used:**
merged_left = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, how='left', left_on='Date', right_on='Date')

So I'm losing everything in the sentiment data, as below:

```html
.         Date  HIGH  LOW  OPEN  CLOSE  sentiment
0 2013-01-04 10734.23 10602.24 10604.50 10688.11 NaN
1 2013-01-07 10743.69 10589.70 10743.69 10599.01 NaN
2 2013-01-08 10602.12 10463.43 10544.21 10508.06 NaN
3 2013-01-09 10620.70 10398.61 10405.67 10578.57 NaN
4 2013-01-10 10686.12 10619.65 10635.11 10652.64 NaN
5 2013-01-11 10830.43 10748.06 10786.14 10801.57 NaN
6 2013-01-15 10952.31 10851.66 10914.65 10879.08 NaN
7 2013-01-16 10806.41 10591.30 10806.41 10600.44 NaN
```

It should look like this below, df2 is a larger dataframe with 2157 rows and many of the dates are not in df (1447 row)... these dates are
not needed, basically I only want the sentiment data for corresponding **dates that exist in df1**:

```html
.       Date  HIGH  LOW  OPEN  CLOSE  sentiment
0 2013-01-04 10734.23 10602.24 10604.50 10688.11 0.092818
1 2013-01-07 10743.69 10589.70 10743.69 10599.01 0.060038
2 2013-01-08 10602.12 10463.43 10544.21 10508.06 0.081649
3 2013-01-09 10620.70 10398.61 10405.67 10578.57 -0.031924
4 2013-01-10 10686.12 10619.65 10635.11 10652.64 0.109111
5 2013-01-11 10830.43 10748.06 10786.14 10801.57 -0.057070
6 2013-01-15 10952.31 10851.66 10914.65 10879.08 0.060790
7 2013-01-16 10806.41 10591.30 10806.41 10600.44 -0.067828
```

Any help would be really appreciated... been on this issue all weekend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is need datetimes in both columns and also default inner join, so `how='inner'` should be omit:

```
 df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
 df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
 merged_left = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Date')
```

Comment: with pleasure! Thanks again. New to this site so just accepted it.